# Generate a list of lists from an iteration

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Here is an example of the problem I'm trying to solve:

```
d=[1,2,3]
e=[d[0],d[1]]

def add_up(x,y):
    return (x + y)
```

My attempt:

```
h=[[add_up(a,b)] for a in e for b in d]
print h
```

output from my attempt

```
[[2], [3], [4], [3], [4], [5]]
```

My desired output: `**[[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]**`

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, use:

```
print [[add_up(a, b) for b in d] for a in e]  # prints [[2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```